# Force JSF/Primefaces to add its CSS inline instead of external file?

Tags: css, email, jsf, primefaces

I was wondering if it is possible to force JSF/Primefaces to include its CSS inline, instead of referring to its external css-file: primefaces.css?

The reason why I'm asking is because I was experimenting with using JSF as an email-template. And few email-clients accept external CSS-files. But most accept inline-css afaik.

Comment: I think (think, not sure) you need to create a custom head renderer. The implementations in OmniFaces and PrimeFaces might serve as an example.

Comment: @Kukeltje that is what I also thought. Probably you will be better of by simply creating a separate faces template with embedded CSS.